# Editing for the blog

Tags: support, blog, editing

I'm not a voluminous writer that can generate lots of content, so creating blog posts isn't really my thing.  I do like to edit, however, and feel that I could effectively contribute in that manner.  Most posts are rife with little errors that I could fix, and some I have suggestions on as to the broader structure I'd like to offer up before these "go to print".

Is there some mechanism for this (I'm somewhat new to the blog) or do approved blog writers just do their own thing and submit at will?

Comment: Have you tried their chatroom?

Answer (score 2):

I made you an account, so you can see drafts or edit any post you feel needs some edits.

Normally bloggers tell the others they are working on something [in our chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/386/gaming-blog-editor-room), so our editors can have a look and try to correct any errors or suggest improvements. Most of the posts exist as drafts for several days, which gives people plenty of time to have a look and see how the posts are shaping up, so that would be the best time to check out the drafts.

So welcome aboard and simply drop by in the chat room to see if who needs any help!

PS: For other users interested in helping out, simply come to the chat room!